# How to handle the both group by particular column name and order by desc particular column name

Tags: sql

Actually i want the data order by column name desc but its also use group by  another column name ...
example:

```
SELECT * ,schemes.depart_id,schemes.scheme_id as s_id FROM `message_details`
left join schemes on schemes.scheme_id=message_details.scheme_id 
left join department on department.id=schemes.depart_id
WHERE message_details.reciver_id=13 or message_details.sender_id=13
GROUP by message_details.scheme_id
HAVING  order by message_details.msg_id desc
```

but result its not correct first row the not highest msg_id

```
SELECT * ,schemes.depart_id,schemes.scheme_id as s_id 
FROM `message_details`
left join schemes on schemes.scheme_id=message_details.scheme_id 
left join department on department.id=schemes.depart_id
WHERE message_details.reciver_id=13 or message_details.sender_id=13
GROUP by message_details.scheme_id
HAVING  order by message_details.msg_id desc
```

i want the group by scheme_id with highest msg_id show in result

Comment: Is that the same query posted twice? Why are you doing GROUP BY? Maybe post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: actually i  handling message chatting  by scheme_id

Comment: Could you please clean up your question, is it one or two queries and what is HAVING doing there? Make sure the query you post has correct syntax and can be executed.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and those backticks are invalid standard SQL). Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Comment: @PRATIKSHAGOYAL . . . `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is just broken logic.  For the columns not in the `GROUP BY`, what columns do you want?  It is sad that you would learn to write this type of SQL.  Your question really needs sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Did the answer below suit your needs? Could you mark it as accepted if that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want *filtering* not *aggregation*.

Without sample data and desired results, it is hard to tell exactly what logic you want to implement.  I suspect it is something along these lines:

```
select . . .   -- list the columns you want here
from message_details md left join
     schemes s
     on s.scheme_id = md.scheme_id left join
     department d
     on d.id = s.depart_id
where 13 in (md.receiver_id, md.sender_id) and
      md.scheme_id = (select max(md2.scheme_id)
                      from message_details md2
                      where 13 in (md2.receiver_id, md2.sender_id)
                     );
```